# Randomly set one-third of na's in a column to one value and the rest to another value

Tags: python-2.7, dask

I'm trying to impute missing values in a dataframe `df`. I have a column `A` with 300 `NaN's`. I want to randomly set 2/3rd of it to `value1` and the rest to `value2`.

Please help.

EDIT: I'm actually trying to this on dask, which does not support item assignment. This is what I have currently. Initially, I thought I'll try to convert all `NA's` to `value1`

```
da.where(df.A.isnull() == True, 'value1', df.A)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: Have you tried [Series.where](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.where) ?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggests, you can solve this with `Series.where`.

The following will work, but I cannot promise how efficient this is. (I suspect it may be better to produce a whole column of replacements at once with `numpy.choice`.)

```
df['A'] = d['A'].where(~d['A'].isnull(), 
    lambda df: df.map(
        lambda x: random.choice(['value1', 'value1', x])))
```

explanation: if the value is not null (NaN), certainly keep the original. Where it is null, replace with the corresonding values of the dataframe produced by the first lambda. This maps values of the dataframe (chunks) to randomly choose the original value for 1/3 and 'value1' for others.

Note that, depending on your data, this likely has changed the data type of the column.